# Activate Application on Screen Unlock

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm writing an application for macOS and I want it to detect when the screen is unlocked and then make itself become the active application. 
I'm trying to use "com.apple.screenIsUnlocked", but it doesn't seem to work (the function doesn't even run). I also tried using NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification where I got the function to run but the app didn't actually activate (presumably because the screen was still locked).
Here is what I currently have (I'm using **Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4**):

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.screenDidUnlock), name:  NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"), object: nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    @objc func screenDidUnlock() {
        NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        print("Did Run")
    }
```

Comment: are you building a malware?

Comment: You really should indicate why you think you need this function.

Comment: No, I am not building malware. I'm trying to build a timer for people who want to have better control about how much time they spend at the computer. The app is supposed to ask the user how much time they intend to spend at the computer and when the timer ends it will automatically put the computer to sleep. Now in order for the user to input the time every time they use the computer I want the app to become active when the screen is unlocked and then ask the user to input the time.

Answer (score 2):

The `com.apple.screenIsUnlocked` notification is posted to the `DistributedNotificationCenter` rather than the `NSWorkspace`'s `notificationCenter`, so the observer should be added like this:

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.screenDidUnlock), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"), object: nil)enter code here
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think apple allows you to run any application in the background.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by running in the background. For example you can easily make an app that does something, say, when a timer inside the application ends, even if that application is not currently active.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean "even if that application is not currently active". if your app is not active you cannot just trigger it, as apple doesn't allow it. you can create a push notification but cannot make the app execute with out the user knowing.  Apple has very strict  [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)  for how—and when—apps can run in the background.

Comment: But I can make an app that activates itself when a timer inside the app ends even if it is not currently active. My problem is that I cannot detect the screen unlocking. Anyway, I'm making this app for personal use and to learn swift, so I don't pay a lot of attention to apple's guidelines (and your link seems to be about iOS not macOS).

Comment: Wrong answer, because this question is about macOS, not about iOS.